# Firebase Dynamic Link not working for Unicode characters

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

The following code for Firebase Dynamic Link works fine for the link containing only English characters.

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
.setLongLink(Uri.parse(longUrl))
.buildShortDynamicLink()
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>()
```

However, if the link contains Unicode characters, it does not work.

when the variable longURL contains English characters - works fine.

when the variable longURL contains Unicide characters - does not work

Please suggest a solution.